# Como contar elementos de RowDataPacket

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente arreglo. y quiero contar las veces que se repite el atributo `materias_idmaterias`.

```js
[ RowDataPacket { idinasistencia: 9, alumno_idalumno: 1, materias_idmaterias: 0 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 10,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 0 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 12,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 13,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 14,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 15,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 359 },
  RowDataPacket {
    idinasistencia: 16,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 359 } ]
```

La intención  es organizar en otro arreglo el numero de `id` y cuantas veces se repite de la siguiente forma:

```
            let ids = [];
            ids[0] = { id: 0, total: 2 };
            ids[1] = { id: 355, total: 3 };
            ids[2] = { id: 359, total: 2 };
```

Comment: El arreglo que planteas no es funcional, corrigelo.

Comment: @fwBasic listo estimado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el `RowDataPacket` puede tratarse como un objeto corriente, yo lo implementaría usando `reduce`, usando el id de la materia como llave:

```js
let rows = [  
   { idinasistencia: 9, 
     alumno_idalumno: 1, 
     materias_idmaterias: 0 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 10,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 0 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 12,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 13,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 14,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 355 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 15,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 359 },
   {
    idinasistencia: 16,
    alumno_idalumno: 1,
    materias_idmaterias: 359 } 
    ];

let agrupado = rows.reduce((accum,row)=>{
   let {materias_idmaterias:id}=row;
   accum[id] = accum[id] || {id, total:0};
   accum[id].total++;
   return accum;
},{});

console.log(agrupado);
```

Llegado ese punto puedes sacar tu array con `Object.values(agrupado)`

Si el `RowDataPacket` por alguna razón requiere el uso de getters, hay un paso adicional, pero la solución es la misma.

**Service Pack**

El método `reduce` de un Array de Javascript ([Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)) itera sobre los elementos de éste, y por cada uno recibe un acumulador y el elemento correspondiente del bucle.

El valor inicial del acumulador se pasa como segundo parámetro al método `reduce`, y en cada bucle rebes retornarlo para que la siguiente iteración no se encuentre con un acumulador indefinido.

El ejemplo más simple sería sumar los elementos:

```
let suma = [1,2,3].reduce((accum,numero)=>{
  accum=accum+numero;
  return accum;
},0);
```

le digo que empiece en cero y recorra el arreglo sumándole al total el valor que estoy revisando. Puedes pensar en esto como si hicieras un `for`

```
let arreglo = [1, 2, 3],
    largo = arreglo.length,
    total = 0;

for(let i; i<largo; i++) {
  total = total + arreglo[i];
}
```

El acumulador puede inicializarse como tú quieras. Puede ser un string al que vas concatenando texto, un número que vas modificando, un arreglo al que le añades o modificas cosas, y en esta respuesta, un objeto al que le vas añadiendo llaves (si no existen) y sobre el valor de esa llave, modificando la propiedad que lleva el conteo.

Entonces, en la primera iteración, cuando accum es un objeto vacío `{}`, no existe `accum[0]` así que lo declara como `accum[0] = {id, total:0}`.

En la línea anterior usé el operador de `destructuración` (en realidad debiera decirse desestructuración yo creo)  para extraer la llave `materias_idmaterias` del elemento, poniéndole el alias `id`. En el fondo:

```
let {materias_idmaterias: id}=row;
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
let id = row.materias_idmaterias;
```

La gracia de usar la destructuración es por ejemplo que puedes sacar N variables del mismo elemento sin usar varias líneas. Por ejemplo, en vez de

```
let idinasistencia = row.idinasistencia;
let alumno_idalumno = row.alumno_idalumno;
let id = row.materias_idmaterias;
```

Es más limpio usar:

```
let {idinasistencia, alumno_idalumno, materias_idmaterias} = row;
```

Pero tú quieres declarar una variable `id` en vez de `materias_idmaterias` así que puedes ponerle un alias:

```
let {idinasistencia, alumno_idalumno, materias_idmaterias: id} = row;
```

Cuando asignas el valor del acumulador, poner:

```
accum[id] = {id, total: 0};
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
accum[id] = {id: id, total: 0};
```

Como id ya está declarado, puedes omitir la asignación explícita. Por ejemplo:

```
let nombre='pedro', 
apellido='perez',
objeto = {};

objeto.nombre = nombre;
objeto.apellido = apellido;
```

Puede escribirse como:

```
let nombre='pedro', 
apellido='perez',
objeto = {nombre, apellido};
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, no entiendo estas líneas `let {materias_idmaterias:id}=row;`   `accum[id] = accum[id] || {id, total:0};`

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación.